# How do I make the snare drum identical every single hit? (Garageband)

Tags: garage-band, snare-drum

I've created a track which involves the Brooklyn drumset's snare (to be more specific the G#0 on the piano roll).

My problem is that the sound varies between 2 different sounds randomly.
One is more hollow and the other is more flat/hitting the edge maybe?

Youtube and Google couldn't help me, but I'm sure one of you guys can! :)

Comment: Is there a way in garageband to check the velocity of the midi note?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, depending on the velocity (how hard you hit your piano key), the sound changes. So a very hard hit would be triggering a different sound than a soft stroke.

If you found a sound you like, look up the velocity of that particular note (you can check the piano roll in Garageband), and set that velocity to all your other notes.